# How to disable support for html5 audio tag in FireFox for testing purposes?

Tags: html, html5-audio

The html5 audio tags I included in my Web page work fine for me. I want to see what happens when someone uses a browser that doesn't support the html5 audio tag.

How can I temporarely disable html5 audio tag support in my browser?

I have disabled all plugins in FF, but the audio tag was still working properly.

Thanks.

Update 2014-11-03:
It occured to me that I could test what happens when the tag is not supported by replacing the "audio" tag by an "audio**s**" tag. Tag "audio**s**" is not supported (it's not even an html tag), so the browser didn't know what to do with it. It's not pretty, but it was good enough for my testing requirements.

Comment: you would probably be best to try your site in a browser that doesn't support html5 audio. [modern.ie is a good place to start, you could grab a virtualbox image of ie8 (which doesnt support html5 audio)]

Comment: I'll check modern.ie, thanks.

Comment: It simply will not work. If you have any Javascript relating to the `audio` element, it could prevent other Javascript from firing. You could use a [polyfill](http://html5polyfill.com/) to make it work or you could detect the browser version and display an error message like "Your browser does not support HTML5 audio" if they are using a legacy browser.